# How to use Python in Blender to change the BEVEL modifier amount, based on a data set in csv (and distribute them in rows)?

Tags: python, modifiers, bevel, csv

I have a csv list of values i want to use to change the Bevel modifier amount for a collection of a big number of cubes. I don't really know Python but tried something based on things I found in youtube, as follows:

```
import csv
import bpy

bar_spacing = 1.5
bar_width = 1

with open ('C:/Users/USER/Downloads/HD1.csv') as f:
    readout = list(csv.reader(f))

for a in readout:
    placement = readout.index (a)
    bpy.ops.mesh.primitive_cube_add(size=1)
    bpy.ops.object.modifier_add(type='BEVEL')
    new_bar = bpy.context.object
    
    for vert in new_bar.data.vertices:
        vert.co[1] += 0.5
        vert.co[0] += placement*bar_spacing + 0.5
        
        new_bar.'bevel' amount = (bar.'bevel' amount, float (a[1])
```

I took the example from [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Xrixs_XuDQo) on how to create data visualization modifying bar sizes, and tried to alter it.
The next picture is what I want to achieve, but with the complete set of 1080 diferent cubes: to have their own bevel amount value from the data, as in the next image:

[image: example of the intended result]

And example of the value/table,

[image]

---

**UPDATE!**
With @cod3R help, I managed to get every cube with it's specific Bevel from the data. Now a new problem: How to distribute them into rows? This is how it looks now and the code i used:

[image]

```
loc_y = 0.0
for data in (0.08,0.39,0.06,0.12,0.27,0.65,0.02,0.55,0.01,0.47,0.13,0.03,0.18,0.14,0.19,0.21,0.01,0.38,0.22,0.10,0.05,0.33,0.13,0.30,0.17,0.49,0.35,0.16,0.53,0.11,0.24,0.39,0.01,0.20,0.26,0.29,0.02,0.18,0.56,0.33,0.94,0.53,0.36,0.24,0.22,0.15,0.15,0.22,0.20,0.30,0.09,0.23,0.02,0.15,0.14,0.44,0.00,0.00,0.20,0.88,0.32,0.05,0.05,0.00,0.16,0.16,0.77,0.57,0.41,0.21,0.08,0.22,0.40,0.83,0.32,0.20,0.04,0.00,0.63,0.24,0.05,0.05,0.60,0.25,0.31,0.08,0.05,0.06,0.00,0.36,0.12,0.29,0.32,0.06,0.55,0.20,0.01,0.30,0.21,0.21,0.18,0.03,0.43,0.27,0.21,0.04,0.16,0.01,0.06,0.00,0.17,0.37,0.00,0.22,0.17,0.35,0.31,0.15,0.01,0.24,0.02,0.06,0.15,0.28,0.18,0.16,0.10,0.38,0.06,0.38,0.25,0.67,1.00,0.53,0.27,0.02,0.27,0.58,0.06,0.01,0.15,0.47,0.13,0.18,0.10,0.00,0.28,0.31,0.30,0.22,0.00,0.04,0.18,0.21,0.06,0.18,0.00,0.33,0.26,0.30,0.22,0.34,0.18,0.38,0.18,0.24,0.48,0.27,0.27,0.30,0.29,0.39,0.49,0.28,0.08,0.51,0.11,0.48,0.24,0.35,0.03,0.26,0.05,0.11,0.20,0.44,0.33,0.15,0.53,0.37,0.37,0.32,0.19,0.36,0.25,0.31,0.01,0.27,0.09,0.36,0.36,0.11,0.23,0.41,0.01,0.26,0.31,0.30,0.13,0.11,0.49,0.13,0.45,0.11,0.25,0.15,0.37,0.12,0.76,0.02,0.19,0.04,0.29,0.27,0.47,0.15,0.02,0.31,0.00,0.47,0.24,0.41,0.24,0.29,0.34,0.10,0.39,0.01,0.28,0.00,0.20,0.39,0.36,0.49,0.44,0.57,0.53,0.64,0.54,0.28,0.36,0.71,0.21,0.50,0.16,0.40,0.19,0.33,0.23,0.00,0.60,0.14,0.39,0.13,0.10,0.00,0.12,0.00,0.01,0.05,0.05,0.20,0.73,0.18,0.06,0.02,0.27,0.47,0.00,0.13,0.19,0.66,0.26,0.08,0.42,0.42,0.37,0.16,0.13,0.18,0.00,0.30,0.34,0.01,0.10,0.29,0.22,0.17,0.17,0.13,0.12,0.27,0.48,0.28,0.08,0.24,0.01,0.11,0.00,0.29,0.30,0.12,0.09,0.34,0.30,0.18,0.08,0.34,0.74,0.18,0.40,0.12,0.23,0.32,0.03,0.66,0.03,0.03,0.31,0.22,0.03,0.41,0.20,0.13,0.45,0.35,0.46,0.12,0.11,0.22,0.35,0.37,0.28,0.47,0.32,0.70,0.33,0.63,0.31,0.28,0.35,0.61,0.39,0.31,0.33,0.35,0.28,0.18,0.58,0.35,0.31,0.26,0.27,0.31,0.13,0.24,0.39,0.26,0.30,0.18,0.48,0.30,0.35,0.22,0.29,0.55,0.30,0.22,0.15,0.15,0.19,0.30,0.33,0.30,0.38,0.39,0.66,0.62,0.52,0.06,0.14,0.44,0.46,0.44,0.44,0.24,0.13,0.25,0.40,0.60,0.25,0.63,0.17,0.00,0.21,0.44,0.25,0.20,0.16,0.06,0.15,0.25,0.18,0.11,0.71,0.09,0.35,0.26,0.27,0.25,0.01,0.01,0.04,0.03,0.08,0.12,0.00,0.03,0.01,0.00,0.01,0.04,0.12,0.04,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.10,0.00,0.06,0.03,0.09,0.02,0.01,0.01,0.12,0.06,0.01,0.01,0.01,0.01,0.08,0.01,0.01,0.01,0.21,0.03,0.03,0.04,0.01,0.01,0.07,0.03,0.01,0.07,0.01,0.05,0.01,0.08,0.01,0.10,0.19,0.06,0.00,0.01,0.14,0.06,0.18,0.01,0.16,0.01,0.02,0.15,0.00,0.01,0.13,0.01,0.01,0.21,0.08,0.06,0.01,0.00,0.00,0.13,0.00,0.11,0.13,0.16,0.00,0.22,0.01,0.15,0.07,0.08,0.00,0.04,0.13,0.17,0.10,0.33,0.42,0.00,0.36,0.13,0.15,0.36,0.01,0.42,0.00,0.01,0.01,0.01,0.25,0.07,0.08,0.35,0.17,0.21,0.32,0.06,0.14,0.44,0.00,0.00,0.32,0.34,0.37,0.19,0.00,0.01,0.24,0.38,0.17,0.01,0.26,0.05,0.00,0.08,0.15,0.01,0.01,0.08,0.22,0.01,0.10,0.17,0.09,0.15,0.01,0.10,0.14,0.09,0.35,0.19,0.02,0.07,0.16,0.18,0.63,0.51,0.34,0.07,0.18,0.26,0.00,0.41,0.12,0.01,0.01,0.23,0.00,0.00,0.05,0.33,0.37,0.09,0.13,0.01,0.18,0.15,0.04,0.11,0.20,0.16,0.01,0.20,0.10,0.23,0.00,0.11,0.19,0.25,0.02,0.22,0.10,0.47,0.05,0.40,0.37,0.42,0.00,0.18,0.01,0.60,0.00,0.55,0.30,0.13,0.01,0.14,0.15,0.18,0.21,0.02,0.07,0.08,0.21,0.23,0.09,0.12,0.20,0.25,0.28,0.18,0.04,0.12,0.29,0.01,0.09,0.30,0.15,0.43,0.52,0.11,0.01,0.11,0.12,0.11,0.21,0.01,0.05,0.18,0.32,0.01,0.11,0.16,0.00,0.01,0.18,0.25,0.15,0.10,0.26,0.19,0.08,0.04,0.07,0.12,0.09,0.01,0.13,0.01,0.18,0.11,0.15,0.06,0.14,0.12,0.20,0.11,0.29,0.17,0.20,0.01,0.27,0.18,0.00,0.06,0.13,0.16,0.17,0.01,0.21,0.31,0.15,0.30,0.12,0.51,0.15,0.13,0.01,0.03,0.01,0.20,0.00,0.00,0.01,0.01,0.05,0.04,0.18,0.29,0.00,0.12,0.01,0.01,0.21,0.20,0.00,0.04,0.01,0.06,0.00,0.11,0.14,0.01,0.04,0.18,0.11,0.02,0.01,0.01,0.01,0.01,0.07,0.35,0.13,0.01,0.18,0.27,0.19,0.00,0.15,0.10,0.19,0.01,0.02,0.14,0.01,0.22,0.01,0.06,0.49,0.40,0.14,0.07,0.01,0.03,0.27,0.06,0.13,0.56,0.02,0.00,0.12,0.17,0.07,0.16,0.06,0.24,0.28,0.19,0.07,0.18,0.02,0.00,0.01,0.00,0.46,0.01,0.09,0.01,0.16,0.01,0.12,0.01,0.13,0.10,0.00,0.12,0.01,0.56,0.00,0.13,0.12,0.01,0.23,0.32,0.01,0.40,0.05,0.26,0.14,0.21,0.38,0.20,0.27,0.15,0.17,0.12,0.31,0.13,0.17,0.30,0.01,0.26,0.18,0.00,0.20,0.05,0.10,0.05,0.01,0.28,0.18,0.08,0.09,0.38,0.30,0.18,0.12,0.00,0.25,0.10,0.00,0.10,0.12,0.01,0.09,0.28,0.00,0.11,0.24,0.13,0.00,0.15,0.05,0.37,0.09,0.01,0.04,0.28,0.09,0.33,0.01,0.01,0.05,0.32,0.11,0.34,0.44,0.58,0.16,0.04,0.57,0.01,0.24,0.27,0.08,0.01,0.19,0.23,0.47,0.19,0.34,0.35,0.59,0.35,0.11,0.08,0.29,0.32,0.33,0.15,0.28,0.29,0.27,0.13,0.07,0.48,0.17,0.27,0.25,0.34,0.01,0.34,0.25,0.04,0.10,0.18,0.61,0.27,0.15,0.53,0.02,0.59,0.14,0.43,0.40,0.20,0.13,0.77,0.37,0.31,0.30,0.24,0.20,0.13,0.23,0.72,0.35,0.11,0.27,0.11,0.18,0.07,0.17,0.14,0.19,0.16,0.31,0.41,0.25,0.21,0.49,0.42,0.37,0.44,0.28,0.34,0.15,0.45,0.01,0.22,0.18,0.08,0.25,0.07,0.10,0.38,0.34,0.23,0.18,0.16,0.05,0.21,0.20,0.10,0.11,0.17,0.02,0.16,0.14,0.15,0.13,0.07,0.04,0.13,0.11,0.12,0.41,0.13,0.10,0.36,0.09,0.08,0.32,0.40,0.84,0.45,0.49,0.23,0.07,0.05,0.24,0.07,0.42,0.06,0.19,0.30,0.13,0.05,0.14,0.11,0.07,0.36,0.17,0.11,0.30,0.07,0.19,0.07,0.04,0.26,0.12,0.32,0.23,0.34,0.34,0.16,0.24,0.11,0.28,0.25,0.29,0.26,0.21,0.04,0.28,0.14,0.51,0.66,0.06,0.22,0.09,0.30,0.24,0.04,0.03,0.19,0.27,0.09,0.32,0.17,0.09,0.38,0.37,0.25,0.05,0.51,0.15,0.04,0.52,0.62,0.11,0.06,0.04,0.28,0.18,0.27,0.14,0.28,0.49,0.20,0.19,0.14,0.18,0.26,0.03,0.10,0.22,0.21,0.29,0.27,0.36,0.06,0.30,0.09,0.07,0.28,0.39,0.39,0.02,0.04,0.11,0.23,0.26,0.01,0.00):
    # Add the cube to the scene and get it
    bpy.ops.mesh.primitive_cube_add(location=(0.0, loc_y, 0.0))
    cube = bpy.context.object
    # Add the bevel modifier
    bevel_mod = cube.modifiers.new(name="MY-Bevel", type='BEVEL')
    bevel_mod.width = data
    # offset the intial location
    loc_y += 3.0
```

Thank you for any advise, example, etc :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the low-level function to add modifiers which allows for direct property access: https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.types.ObjectModifiers.html#bpy.types.ObjectModifiers.new

```
import bpy

# Get the object
obj = bpy.context.scene.objects['Cube']

# Add the modifier the low level function and set the bevel amount
bevel_mod = obj.modifiers.new(name="MY-Bevel", type='BEVEL')
bevel_mod.width = 0.01
```

########################################################

One simple loop to add cubes based on the data should do:

```
import bpy

loc_y = 0.0
for data in (1.0, 0.5, 0.25, 0.1, 0.01):
    # Add the cube to the scene and get it
    bpy.ops.mesh.primitive_cube_add(location=(0.0, loc_y, 0.0))
    cube = bpy.context.object
    # Add the bevel modifier
    bevel_mod = cube.modifiers.new(name="MY-Bevel", type='BEVEL')
    bevel_mod.width = data
    # Offset the initial location
    loc_y += 3.0
```

[image]

**EDIT** Setting up the rows is also fairly simple:

```
import bpy

bevel_amounts = [1.0, 0.5, 0.25, 0.1, 0.01]
loc_x = 0.0
loc_y = 0.0
offset = 3.0
items_row = 7

for i, data in enumerate(bevel_amounts, start=1):
    # Add the cube to the scene and get it
    bpy.ops.mesh.primitive_cube_add(location=(loc_x, loc_y, 0.0))
    cube = bpy.context.object
    # Add the bevel modifier
    bevel_mod = cube.modifiers.new(name="MY-Bevel", type='BEVEL')
    bevel_mod.width = data
    # Offset the initial location
    loc_y += offset
    # Add a new row 
    if i % items_row == 0:
        loc_x += offset
        # Reset y
        loc_y = 0.0
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you! that worked perfectly. I've updated the question with a new (smaller) question. I now have the correct cubes with their specific bevel. How can I distribute them into rows (say, 7 cubes per raw)?